# simplest way to combine two Django projects

Tags: django, virtualenv, uwsgi

Best case scenario:  Just modify  the urlpatterns of one of them to include the urlpatterns of the other.

But as of now they both have seperate settings.py, seperate DB's, seperate directories.  I assume I may have to somehow merge their two settings.py, include one of them in the other's INSTALLED_APPS, and resolve a bunch of directory issues.  Can I somehow just have one invoke the other through urls.py and forego all the above.  Any website documentation covering all this in detail, that's the main thing.  Sorry if this has been asked.  The problem is the existing Django project is running under one uwsgi process on the server, and adding another uwsgi process bumps it up to another account level.

Comment: Well, I'm just going to put a link to the other project directory in one project,  add a line in urls.py and see what happens...

Comment: I'm necromanser but how you resolve this situation?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you mean by "invoke the other through URLs.py", but you can include URLs from one app within another very easily. For example:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('', url(r'^polls/', include('polls.urls')))
```

That will include all the URLs in the polls app. You can read more on it here:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial03/#decoupling-the-urlconfs

Comment: No I was aware of this, just didn't know if one of the projects had to be included in the INSTALLED_APPS of the other, and share the same DB.  I hadn't really seen any examples of one Django project invoking and entirely different one running on the same server process.

Comment: take a look at the rest of that page, and the next one. Theres lots of bits on running apps within one another.

Comment: FYI, they're having to do a fair bit of work just to make that simple polls app integratable into another project, for a nontrivial app even more involved I guess

Answer (score 0):

This is state of my knowledge now.  Something like uwsgi and I guess other server schemes ask for the specification of a single settings.py as a parameter.   So as far as integrating multiple Django  projects in a single uwsgi process, they will have to share a single settings.py.  The only problem there is only one setting for MEDIA_URL and MEDIA_ROOT.  And the only solution I see is putting the media from both projects in one folder - seems unreasonable. Am I missing something.